# Why is my spirulina biomass getting destroyed in my new photobioreactor?

Tags: cell-culture, biotechnology

I have a 500L flat plate photobioreactor in my backyard. Whenever I add my culture to the PBR, after 3-4 days of growth, the culture becomes transparent and my biomass is wasted.

I add the stock at a 1:10 ratio (50 litres). My culture medium is Baum. The temperature varies between 12 to 25 degrees Celsius in 24 hours, and the pH is between 9 to 10. Circulation is done by an air pump and a water pump (for circulation of the biomass across the system, from one flat plate to the next).

Maybe it is caused by shock or the sheer stress of the water pump? Or something (like brass valves) releasing some toxic substance into the culture? What should I do?

Comment: Are you only growing spirulina? sounds like an infection of some kind to me.

Comment: Things to try - can you grow the spirulina elsewhere (i.e. not in your reactor, but in a jar or something similar)? This tests whether it is something to do with the reactor. Can you sub-sample from the reactor on days 1 -4 and get growth from those samples outside the reactor (also check pH etc at same time)? This tests whether there is a problem like infection in the reactor. Is your ratio too high - given log growth a 1:10 will consume all the nutrients pretty quickly - do you need more light. Does the temp rise too high inside the reactor (not air temp)? How about O2 concentration?

Comment: please add a bit more details about your setup,do you aerate the water,how do you fertilize your algae,where do you get water from for your setup?

Comment: please enlighten me what is baum?

Comment: @MaximilianPress It seems under a microscope. Only spirulina, but their springs were straightened by self-shading. We also changed the stock and water several times.

Comment: @bob1 Thank you. I'll work on it. The ratio for the first time was 1:20. The light is perfect (flat plate in the backyard). The mentioned temperature was the temperature inside the biomass. Aeration is done by an air pump and circulation is done by a water pump.

Comment: @trondhansen Same as before. We grew spirulina under the same conditions (water from water refinery kiosks (they are common in my city, as our drinking water is full of arsenic). We add all the materials (Baum) needed by the biomass at the beginning and aerate the system every 20 minutes with an air pump.

Comment: @trondhansen Baum culture described in `Heinsoo, D. (2014). Cultivation of Spirulina on Conventional and Urine Based Medium in a Household Scale System.` I do not recommend it.

Comment: Cyanophage? https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10811-012-9853-x

Comment: @acvill Thanks, but I don't think so, since the sample is growing in the lab.